# Generate unique hash from filename

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I'm looking to generate a unique random hash that has a miniscule chance of being duplicated. It should only contain numbers, and I want it to be 4 characters long. I have the file path in the form of

```
filepath = "c:\\users\\john\\filename.csv"
```

Now, I'd like to only select the "filename" part of that string and create a hash from that filename, though I want it to be different each time so if two users upload a similarly named file it will likely generate a different hash code. What's the best way to go about doing this?

I will be using this hash to append "001", "002", etc. on to create student IDs.

Comment: 4 digits is simply not enough to cover all combinations of file names.

Comment: _" a unique random hash that has a miniscule chance of being duplicated, 4 digits long"_  That is unrealistic.

Comment: First or Last 4 characters of the FAT 8.3 "short name" ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter nitpick- at least at the current edit, he said 4 characters, not 4 digits.  36 ^ 4 is quite a large address space.

Comment: @ChrisShain "It should only contain numbers"...

Comment: @Chris Shain Missed that as well.

Comment: You can get the "filename" part of the string fairly easily with String.Split. The hashing part is a bit trickier since it can only be 0000-9999. If you know all the filenames at the start, you can put them in some random order and assign hash values that way. That'll prevent duplicates. Otherwise, you could try using a part, like the first 10 bits, of the MD5 (or other hash algorithm) hash. Using just a part means you might get duplicates though.

Comment: @user141603: Don't use `String.Split` for file paths but [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Very nice. You learn something new every day. I had no idea that function existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generating a [unique hash from a file's filename](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9560/Get-MD5-and-SHA-1-SHA1-of-any-file) is fairly simple.

However...

> It should only contain numbers, and I want it to be 4 characters long.

With only 4 numeric characters, you're going to be guaranteed to have a collision with 1000 different files, and will likely be hit quite a bit sooner.  This makes it impossible to have a "minuscule chance of being duplicated".

---

Edit in response to comments:

You could do some simple type of hash, though this will give quite a few collisions:

```
string ComputeFourDigitStringHash(string filepath)
{
     string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
     int hash = filename.GetHashCode() % 10000;
     return hash.ToString("0000");
}
```

This will give you a 4 digit "hash" from the filename portion of the string.  Note that it will have a lot of collisions, but it will give you something you can use.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The main goal is to have it output a different hash if given the same filename. I understand that eventually duplicates may occur, but this is fine as long as I can count on, say 5 duplicate filenames, having a good chance of generating a different hash.

Comment: Also, I want to generate a 4 character hash. I feel like this should be fairly simple, much more so than the linked project. Is there no built in method to do this?

Comment: @Hyung There is no built-in method to do what you want.  With 4 numeric digits and a general purpose hashing routine, you're going to get duplicates fairly easily - that's just not a lot to work with.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I'm just doing a proof-of-concept here, would you be able to provide me with a hashing method that will take an input string and output a digit-only string that I can then take the first 4 characters of? That should be good enough.

Comment: @Hyung Added some code for you - it'll have a lot of collisions, as it's restricted to 4 digits...

Comment: @ReedCopsey The article you linked to is about hashing the contents of the file, not the file name. Just letting you know.

Comment: @user141603 Yes, but in the end, it's about hashing *data* in general

Comment: When I try to use ComputeFourDigitStringHash I end up with the error
"'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetHash' and no extension method 'GetHash' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found". Though GetHashCode() works, is that a comparable method?

Comment: @Hyung Should ahve been GetHashCode() - I typed it too fast.